# Get User by email address using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get the information if the user Exists (using email Address) in Azure AD or not using Microsoft Graph API (Version 5.17.0).

```
 var myself = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();  // This Code Works

 var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync(c =>
                {
                    c.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "mail" };
                    c.QueryParameters.Top = 1;
                    c.QueryParameters.Filter = $"mail eq {userEmail}";
                })!.Value?.FirstOrDefault();  // This doesn't work
```

I am getting an exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.

Here are my settings in appsettings.json

```
  "GraphApi": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
      "Scopes": "User.Read.All"
  }
```

Also, I have given permissions Users.Read.All on Azure Portal
[image]

Here is my code while Configuration

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("GraphApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Couldn't figure out what else I am missing.

Comment: Try Postman to debug : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api#postman

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, your comment pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I figured it out,

I had to use this to get user by email address

```
var result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userEmail].GetAsync();
```